# Do I have to malloc for NULL pointers? When do I exactly need to malloc for a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a little confused as to when should I malloc space for a pointer. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to malloc if you want to point to a new piece of memory.  NULL means not pointing to any memory, so no.

Comment: It's somewhat unusual to `malloc()` space for a pointer, whether `NULL` or otherwise.

Comment: @EOF: Just to make sure the OP understands your comment, you `malloc()` space for the pointer to point to, not for the pointer itself.

Comment: The question is like "Do I have to buy a phone for a blank phone number?" - 1) no, that's silly and 2) what does it even mean to "buy a phone for a phone number"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `malloc` is used to allocate a certain amount of memory during the execution of a program. The malloc function will request a block of memory from the heap.

> I'm a little confused as to when should I malloc space for a pointer.

You don't have to use `malloc` always to use a pointer. `malloc` should only be used when you need to request a space dynamically during run time. For example,

```
char arr[20]="Stack";
char *ptr; //It is pointer
ptr = arr;
printf("%s", ptr);
```

In the above example, i haven't used `malloc` but still i can use the pointer `ptr`. The only thing that matters is the pointer should point to some valid memory location at which you intend to work. Either assign address of a variable to a pointer

```
int a;
int *ptr=&a;
```

Or

Request for memory during run-time using `malloc`.

```
int *ptr=malloc(sizeof(int));
```

> Do I have to malloc for NULL pointers?

The answer is No. In computing, a null pointer has a value reserved for indicating that the pointer does not refer to a valid object. `NULL` is the value assigned to pointers which means they are not referring to valid object. Just assign `NULL` value to a pointer.

```
int *ptr=NULL:
```